# Retrieving part of a string using jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I know how I would achieve this using PHP, but with jQuery / JavaScript I'm not sure how to, here's the string I'm dealing with (It's the name attribute from a input element):

```
Field[0][some_random_text]
```

I want to retrieve the value `some_random_text` and slap it in a variable, I guess I would usually use regex to accomplish this task but not sure how this is done in JavaScript. Here are some characteristics of this name attribute.

- It will always be in this format `string[string][string]`
- Each of the strings can be any length

How would I get the `some_random_text` string?

I'd like to stick to the standard set of functions if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex, like this:

```
var part = /\]\[(.+?)\]$/.exec('Field[0][some_random_text]')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally a fan of split():

```
// name being the variable that is holding the string.
name.split('[')[2].replace(']','');
```

Answer (score 1):

door number 4:

```
var s = "Field[0][some_random_text]";
var x = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("[")+1, s.length - 1);
alert(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too! This did in fact work, would be interesting (when I learn how :D) to compare the performance of your an SLaks answer. Many thanks! +1

Comment: did a simple test, a loop of 100.000 iterations, substring method took 38ms, regex 396ms *gloat* :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming Jquery.  If I understand, you are trying to get the name attribute.

var name = $("img").attr("name"));

"img" can be any of a number of ways of selecting an element, more at http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: He's asking how to to parse an arbitrary string.

Comment: Hi there, I actually wanted to get a portion of the attribute value, SLaks answer achieved this very well. Thanks :)